# Foreach loop not acting like numerous if statements

Tags: php, foreach

So I had a series of if statements in PHP that were generating some output - and the code was working fine - I then tried to create a foreach loop to consolidate the code but the output is way different. Not all of the fields output all the time, and the rounding is different then when I output the information.

Sample is on http://pagliocco.com/ManaCalcTest.php

Code snippet is below

```
$output = array(
            $forest => " Forests", 
            $island => " Islands", 
            $mountain => " Mountains", 
            $swamps => " Swamps", 
            $plains => " Plains");

foreach ($output as $value => $landName){
    if(round($value) > 0) {
        echo round($value) ." ". $landName ."<BR>";
    }
}

echo "<BR><BR>";

if(round($forest) > 0)
{
echo round($forest);
echo " Forests";
echo "<BR>";
}
if(round($island) > 0)
{
echo round($island);
echo " Islands";
echo "<BR>";
}
if(round($mountain) > 0)
{
echo round($mountain);
echo " Mountains";
echo "<BR>";
}
if(round($plains) > 0)
{
echo round($plains);
echo " Plains";
echo "<BR>";
}
if(round($swamps) > 0)
{
echo round($swamps);
echo " Swamps";
echo "<BR>";
}
```

Comment: What are the values of $forest, $island, etc?

Comment: They are integers - but problem and solution provided below - thanks ShoeLace1291!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how you define your output array:

```
$output = array(
        $forest => " Forests", 
        $island => " Islands", 
        $mountain => " Mountains", 
        $swamps => " Swamps", 
        $plains => " Plains"
);
```

I am assuming this is about M:TG and those variables have integer values. When those values are not unique, what you end up doing is pushing the same keys into the array multiple times. When you do that, the last key pushed "wins" and the values for the previously pushed keys are lost.

For example, if `$plains == 0` then your array will have the value `" Plains"` associated with the key `0` and all other types of basic land that appear zero times will not be in the array at all. You can confirm this with `var_dump($output)`.

The solution is of course to do it backwards: use those values *you know* are unique (basic land names) as keys, and the quantity of each as values.

```
$output = array(
        "Forests" => $forest, 
        "Islands" => $island, 
        // etc
);

foreach ($output as $landName => $value) ...
```

Comment: im wondering if theres a different type of array i can use that will keep all the values in there - time to hit php.net heh

Comment: @TPup: No, just swap keys and values.

Comment: Thank you Jon - I was glad to have had help finding the problem - I come from the IRC days where asking for the solution is bad lol - so I was glad to find the problem and even happier that the answer you provided was easy heh. Thanks!